# how to use driver.get(url) from extracted href list from the page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am wanting to go to https://www.bookmaker.com.au/sports/soccer, extract the soccer urls which it does.  I am then wanting to go to each of those webpages through driver.get(url).  I have done this as a list and then it extracts the data for each of those urls and place in pandas.  I am stuck at getting driver.get(url) for each of those links extracted.  Any help appreciated.

Css/href for driver.get(url):

```
url = #a[class *= 'matches-filter__region']

import time
import pandas as pd
import webdriver_manager.chrome
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
###########################################################################################################################################################

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
service = Service('driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.bookmaker.com.au/sports/soccer')
aa = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class *= 'matches-filter__region']")
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class *= 'matches-filter__region']")))
################################################################################################################

for url in aa:
    aa = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class *= 'matches-filter__region']")
    driver.get(aa)

##############################################################################
```

#Full Code https://pastebin.com/W0VqaKVD

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error or what. Maybe you should  `get_atttribute('href')`?

Comment: if you want to get something from these pages then you should run code inside `for`-loop but you run code after `for`-loop

Comment: @furas I am wanting to use driver.get(url) the url being extracted href.  Atm it is not going to the extracted href webpages individually through driver.get(url)

Comment: @furas the below is probably not correct way to do it - for url in aa:
    aa = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class *= 'matches-filter__region']")
    driver.get(aa)

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. If you want url then you may `aa.get_atttribute('href')`. If it relative url then you may have to add `https://...` to create absolute url. And if you want to scrape some data from this page then yoou have to run other code inside this `for`-loop

Comment: @furas I extracted the href and made that a list.  How can I use driver.get() command successfully to go to those list hrefs?

Comment: I don understand what is the problem - you need only for-loop to use it . But first check if you have correct urls. You may have relative urls and you may have to add `https://...` to create absolute url. Maybe use `print(url)` to see what you have in variables. And if you get error then show it in question.

Comment: @furas At the moment I am getting [] instead of href which is weird but fixable.   How do I use the for loop correctly to driver.get each website in the extracted links?

Comment: you have to use `aa = driver.find_elements(..)` before `for url in aa:` or use `for url in driver.find_elements(..)`

Comment: if you get empty lis tthen maybe you use wrong selector. Maybe server send it with diffferent classes. And you would have to check `HTML` which you get from server.

Comment: @ iwasstandingathedairynextminut, the list returning the correct elemenets, did you try the code posted as answer.

Comment: @furas Are you able to able to produce the working result of chrome going to the extracted href through driver.get()?   for url in aa: and below ?-  This is correct way of doing this part of code?

Comment: I think all problem is that you have few mistakes in code. First you have to get `aa` before `for`-loop, second you have to use `get(url)` instead of `get(aa)`, I didn't run code yet, but you may have other mistakes.

Comment: I can't open this page - maybe it blocked in my country if it is page with gambling, or if page don't allow for access from my country

Comment: @furas yeah a vpn for australia is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using VPN I could connect and I found few problems with code

1. you have to get `aa` before `for`-loop
2. `find` gives reference to objects in browser's memory but when you use `get()` then it removes these objects from memory to create new object from new page, and results from `find()` are useless. You have to use `.get_attribute('href')` to get urls as strings.
3. you have to use `for`-loop to run `get()` for every string from list and you have to run other code inside this loop. And after loop you have to create `DataFrame`

This is code without code inside loop. But at least it visits all urls.

```
# --- before loop ---

all_a = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class *= 'matches-filter__region']")

# get URLs as strings
all_urls = []
for item in all_a:
    all_urls.append(item.get_attribute('href'))

# shorter    
#all_urls = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in all_a]

team1List = []
backOddsList = []
team2List = []
layOddsList = []

# --- loop ---

# visit all pages and get teams

for url in all_urls:
    print(url)

    driver.get(url)

    # here (inside loop) all code to get teams from active page

# --- after loop ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team1': team1List,
    'Back Odds': backOddsList,
    'Team2': team2List,
    'Lay Odds': layOddsList
})
 
df.to_excel('bookmaker.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code, I checked, it is working, navigating to all the 15 urls in the same browser window:

```
diff_country_urls = []
for i in range(len(aa)):
    diff_country_urls.append(aa[i].get_attribute("href"))

for url in diff_country_urls:
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: I am wanting thse values and to go to driver.get for each of those - a[class *= 'matches-filter__region']

Comment: Above code will open every url in browser, there are 15 urls.

Comment: Yeah it does not do that for me.  I will try bug testing further tonight